# how to path parameter to html form

Tags: javascript, html

My form code is

```
<form id="test-form" class="white-popup-block mfp-hide">
      <div class="popup_box ">
        <div class="popup_inner">
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <form action="#">
            <div class="row">
              <p>
                Description
              </p>

              <!-- <div class="col-xl-12">
                <button type="submit" class="boxed-btn3">
                  Close
                </button>
              </div> -->
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

how do I call the form :

```
<a class="popup-with-form amira_margin2"
   href="#test-form">More</a>
```

I want to send different title and description each time I open the form, How to send it ?

Comment: Where are you getting the title/description from?

Comment: static value , I have 4 more buttons and want to show different title and description with each one

Answer (score 0):

Add some IDs to `<h3>` and `<p>`.
And use `innerHTML` to replace the title and the description.
HTML code:

```
<form id="test-form" class="white-popup-block mfp-hide">
      <div class="popup_box ">
        <div class="popup_inner">
          <h3 id="_h3">Title</h3>
          <form action="#">
            <div class="row">
              <p id="_p">
                Description
              </p>

              <!-- <div class="col-xl-12">
                <button type="submit" class="boxed-btn3">
                  Close
                </button>
              </div> -->
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

JavaScript code:

```
document.getElementById('_button1').click(function(e) { //_button1 is the id of your first button.
   //Change the contents of the title
   document.getElementById('_h3').innerHTML = "Hello world from button1!";
   //And the description
   document.getElementById('_p').innerHTML = "Hello world from button1!";
};
```

Then add this script for all your buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Add form-title class to your h3 and form-description class to your p tag. And add similar class like button and a different class to each button like button_one, button_two for select. Check code below for more details.

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
  buttons.forEach((button) => {
   button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let formTitle = document.querySelector('.form-title');
    let formDescription = document.querySelector('.form-description');
    if (button.classList.contains('button_one')) {
     formTitle.innerHTML = 'Button One Title';
     formDescription.innerHTML = 'Button One Description';
    } else if (button.classList.contains('button_two')) {
     formTitle.innerHTML = 'Button Two Title';
     formDescription.innerHTML = 'Button Two Description';
    } else if (button.classList.contains('button_three')) {
     formTitle.innerHTML = 'Button Three Title';
     formDescription.innerHTML = 'Button Three Description';
    } else if (button.classList.contains('button_four')) {
     formTitle.innerHTML = 'Button Four Title';
     formDescription.innerHTML = 'Button Four Description';
    } else {
     return null;
    }
   });
  });
```

```html
<a class="popup-with-form button button_one amira_margin2"
   href="#test-form">Button One</a>
   <br>
 <a class="popup-with-form button button_two amira_margin2"
   href="#test-form">Button Two</a>
   <br>
 <a class="popup-with-form button button_three amira_margin2"
   href="#test-form">Button Three</a>
   <br>
 <a class="popup-with-form button button_four amira_margin2"
   href="#test-form">Button Four</a>
   <br>

 <form id="test-form" class="white-popup-block mfp-hide">
      <div class="popup_box ">
        <div class="popup_inner">
          <h3 class="form-title">Title</h3>
          <form action="#">
            <div class="row">
              <p class="form-description">
                Description
              </p>

              <!-- <div class="col-xl-12">
                <button type="submit" class="boxed-btn3">
                  Close
                </button>
              </div> -->
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```